# DNN upgrade to new version

Tags: c#, vb.net, dotnetnuke

I have a 06.01.05 and want to upgrade to latest version. I backed up old site and upload the upgrade files to a sub domain. when I browse http://www.mysite.com/install/install?mode=upgrade, I see a 404 error page. I want t know how to register the subdomain for upgrade path?

Comment: Are you just missing the `.aspx` from your path?

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade your DNN installation, you only have to unzip the upgrade package at the root of your website with overwriting existing files.
Then, load the website URL (http://www.mywebsite.com for example). It should redirect you on the upgrade wizard.
If it doesn't, you also could browse http://www.mywebsite.com/install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade (don't forget to add the aspx extension to the page in the URL). FYI, in web.config, the "AutoUpgrade" value may block the automatic redirection to the upgrade wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You likely just need to add a Portal Alias (portalalias table) for the URL that you want to access for the subdomain, without the Alias DNN won't know what site to load, which can cause 404 errors.

The other thing to keep in mind is that you need to ensure that subdomain's DNS points to the server you are trying to load the site on.